# Search Multiple Tables with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables:

```
____________________   ____________________   ____________________
posts                  tags                   posts_x_tags
____________________   ____________________   ____________________
| id | title | body    | id | tag_name        | post_id | tag_id
```

posts and tags have a many to many relationship.
Is is possible to do a search for posts.body OR posts.title OR tags.tag_name.

This gets me close but returns so many duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p
INNER JOIN posts_x_tags x ON p.id = x.post_id 
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id = x.tag_id 
AND t.tag LIKE '%a%'
OR p.title LIKE '%a%'
OR p.body LIKE '%a%';
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT DISTINCT ... in order to remove duplicates from result set.

Comment: Ya tried that. I get this: "The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable."

Comment: @Pardoner: YIKES!! You're using `TEXT` as a datatype somewhere?!??!?!? STOP DOING THAT RIGHT NOW! This type is deprecated - DO NOT USE IT - by all means, use `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead (and these types can be used in a SELECT, too!)